Example of Minimum Variance Estimator with Rate worst than $\frac{1}{n}$
Consider $n$ i.i.d. observation from a distribution $p(X| \theta)$. Suppose we are interested in estimating $\theta$ from this data.
I am interested in an example that would show that:

There exists a consistent estimator of $\theta$. Denote it by $\hat{\theta}$. In other words, I want this problem to be well-defined.
The variance of the 'best' (minimum variance) does not converge at the usual rate of  $\frac{1}{n}$, but at a slower rate.

There is quite a bit of results in the literature that show that at least MLE (under proper) regularity conditions converges at the rate $\frac{1}{n}$.  It seems to me that if such an example exists, then the Fisher information must be zero for this setting.

Parametric estimators typically converge at $\sqrt{n}$ in i.i.d settings. Under weak conditions, most estimators that minimize a criterion (such as M-estimators, which include log-likelihood) will get this rate. To get a rate slower than $\sqrt{n}$ you need to focus on non-parametric estimators.

For example, suppose you compute a conditional mean $\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X = x]$, and you do it by either subsetting observations with values close to $X = x$ or giving all observations some weight depending on their distance to $X$, i.e. a kernel estimator. Here the rate is slower than $\sqrt{n}$ because the "effective sample size" used to compute the estimator is not the full sample.

@Boby: do you need to know what the minimum variance estimator is explicitly or is it enough to know that its variance decreases slower than $1/n$? And do you care about finite-sample variance or only asymptotic variance? Also, the estimator typically won't have asymptotically negligible bias: do you want the minimum MSE estimator?

@ThomasLumley I don't need a explicit estimator construction. I just want to know that there are example in which the variance vanishes slower than the usual $1/n$. So a lower bound on the variance would be enough for me.  Asymptotic result is also fine.   I don't care so much a bout the bias, but the estimator does have to be consistent.

@ecnmetrician I agree that in non-parametric settings you can get slower rates.  But I do  care about a parametric example with a slow rate.  There must exist one (I hope :)).

The maximum score estimator (proposed in Manski 1975) is known to converge at $n^{1/3}$ for binary discrete choice models, if one does not make any assumptions about the distribution of the errors.

@ecnmetrician do you have a reference for this?

https://economics.sas.upenn.edu/system/files/2021-09/Econometrics%20Lunch%2012062021.pdf

There's a result of Le Cam saying roughly that any reasonable fixed-dimensional Euclidean parameter which can be estimated consistently can be estimated at $\sqrt{n}$ rate.  I've been trying to find a clean statement of it published somewhere. Lemma 7 in Le Cam (1973) says that any parameter in a compact subset of Euclidean space can be estimated at $\sqrt{n}$ rate under a condition that says two distributions with small distance in the parameter must have small Hellinger distance and vice versa.  And if a parameter can be estimated consistently then we can eventually pin it down to a compact neighbourhood of the true value.
Also, I think you MAY need to worry a bit more about bias that just wanting consistency. Consider the semiparametric problem of density estimation that @ecnmetrician mentions in the comments.  The optimal MSE rate is $n^{-4/5}$, but you can get variances arbitrarily close to $n^{-1}$ if you're willing to accept biases decreasing to zero at arbitrarily slow rates.

Does this mean that one should concentrate on mean square error, not variance? Will that also, under this conditions, have the rate $1/n$?

One should probably concentrate on mean squared error, yes.  When the MSE is $O(1/n)$ you will often? typically? be able to get asymptotically negligible bias and optimal variance but that's much harder when the MSE isn't $O(1/n)$.

Thanks. This is a great answer.
